# Trying to parse XML

Tags: ios, xml

I am trying to parse the following XML File:

[image]

However when I parse it:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentElementName = elementName;
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([currentElementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        NSLog(@"Link: %@",string);
    }
}
```

I get the following NSLOG:

```
 Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/114014058@N06/
 Link: 

 Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/114014058@N06/
 Link: 

 Link: 


 Link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/114014058@N06/11865861164/
 Link:
```

As you see the URL I want is not appearing and there is a bunch of empty URLs.

Why?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I tried Rhythmic Fistman's answer but all I get is:

`link is (null)`

Comment: You can't expect much help without posting your relevant code.

Comment: Why are you logging the link in the `foundCharacters` method? The URL you want is the value of the `href` attribute of the `link` element which you can access in the `didStartElement:` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried that but I got `link is (null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `didStartElement` callback.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
```

When `elementName` is `@"link"` your url should be in `attributeDict[@"href"]`.

e.g.

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
            NSLog(@"link is %@\n", attributeDict[@"href"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I get: `link is (null)`

Comment: What's in the attribute dict?

Comment: It appears that there is no keys in the attribute dict

Comment: Can you make the xml available? My code is extrapolated from something  that parsed iframes.

Comment: The xml is above in my question

Comment: That's a picture of xml, I meant the textual version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find element starts in didStartElement, so change state there.  When you get foundCharacters, check that you are in the right state, then the characters there are what you want.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // assume currentElementName starts out nil.  if we find "generator", enter
    // "generator" state.  if we're in "generator" state and find "link" then enter
    // "link" state, which is our target state

    if ([currentElementName isEqualToString:@"generator"] && [elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
        currentElementName = @"link";

        // now we're in the tag we want to be in.  get attributes from 
        // the attributeDict, if you need the tag body, check for "link" state in foundChars

        NSLog(@"here are the attributes we want %@", attributeDict);

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"generator"]) {
        currentElementName = @"generator";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need at all for the `foundCharacters` method to solve the OP's question. You access the `href` attribute in the `didStartElement:` method.

Comment: yeah, i see that now.  that xml printing was small.  trying to address the state management not covered in the other answer

Comment: There's no state to manage. The other answer is correct as-is.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, I think the OP wants the link tag inside the generator tag.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I got focused on how to get the actual URL value from a link tag and lost sight of the fact that the OP needs details about a specific link tag. Your answer sort of covers how to find your way to the desired link tag but it doesn't cover how to get the actual link value.